# React: Child component doesn't get updated values when reset function is triggered in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Update:

### I think the problem is that Child 2 components are not rerendering because there are the same props when handleReset() is triggered in parent component.. but how can I make them rerendering? I tried with useEffect but nothing happens.

I'm struggling for several hours with the following issue:
I have a parent component in which I have some values passed from useState to child 1 (CustomerData) then to child 2 (-AddressForm and -CustomerForm).

My problem is that when the handleReset() from parent component is triggered, the values from child2 (AddressForm and CustomerForm) are not updated and I don't understand why. I Think that Child 2 components are not rerendering when I reset the values and somehow I need to pass in some other way the stated in the set hook from handleReset().

If somebody can help me solve this issue please. Here are my components:

### Parent component:

```
function WidgetCustomerData(props): JSX.Element {
    const customerDataTest = {
        customerFirstName: 'firstNameTest',
        customerLastName: 'lastNameTest',
        customerPhone: '1313212',
        customerEmail: 'test@test.com',
        customerAddress: 'Musterstraße',
        customerAddressNo: '12',
        customerZip: '80335',
        customerCity: 'Berlin',
        deviceAddress: 'Straße',
        deviceAddressNo: '152',
        deviceZip: '32214',
        deviceCity: 'Hamburg',
    };

  const [customerData, setCustomerData] = useState({
    addressValue: customerDataTest.customerAddress,
    addressValueNr: customerDataTest.customerAddressNo,
    addressValueZip: customerDataTest.customerZip,
    addressValueCity: customerDataTest.customerCity,
    customerFirstName: customerDataTest.customerFirstName,
    customerLastName: customerDataTest.customerLastName,
    customerPhone: customerDataTest.customerPhone,
    customerEmail: customerDataTest.customerEmail,
    deviceAddress: customerDataTest.deviceAddress,
    deviceAddressNo: customerDataTest.deviceAddressNo,
    deviceZip: customerDataTest.deviceZip,
    deviceCity: customerDataTest.deviceCity
  })

  const handleClose = () => {
    props.handleClose();
}

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e && e.preventDefault();
        const formUrl = 'https://fetch.mock/widget-customer-data/addCustomerData';
        const formData = new FormData(e.target);
        for (const [name, value] of formData) {
            console.log(`${name}: ${value}`);
        }

        const response = await fetch(formUrl.toString(), {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            credentials: 'same-origin',
        });

        const data = await response.json();
    };

    const handleReset = () => {
        console.log('handleReset ----');
        
      setCustomerData({
      addressValue: customerDataTest.customerAddress,
      addressValueNr: customerDataTest.customerAddressNo,
      addressValueZip: customerDataTest.customerZip,
      addressValueCity: customerDataTest.customerCity,
      customerFirstName: customerDataTest.customerFirstName,
      customerLastName: customerDataTest.customerLastName,
      customerPhone: customerDataTest.customerPhone,
      customerEmail: customerDataTest.customerEmail,
      deviceAddress: customerDataTest.deviceAddress,
      deviceAddressNo: customerDataTest.deviceAddressNo,
      deviceZip: customerDataTest.deviceZip,
      deviceCity: customerDataTest.deviceCity
    })
    };

    return (
        <div className="customer-data">
            <Dialog
                onClose={handleClose}
        open={props.open}
                aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
                PaperProps={{
                    style: { borderRadius: 20, minWidth: '80%', maxHeight: 'fit-content' },
                }}>
                <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={handleClose} />
                <Typography style={{ marginTop: 20, paddingLeft: 48, fontSize: 32, fontWeight: 600 }}>Kundendaten bearbeiten</Typography>
                {/* <DialogContent> */}
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div style={{ paddingLeft: 48, paddingRight:48 }}>
              <CustomerData
                customerData={customerData}
              />
            </div>
                        <DialogActions>
                            <ResetButton onClick={handleReset} variant="contained" color="primary">
                                Reset
                            </ResetButton>
                            <SaveButton type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
                                Save
                            </SaveButton>
                        </DialogActions>
                    </form>
                {/* </DialogContent> */}
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
}
export default WidgetCustomerData;
```

### Child1

```
export default ({nextStepAction, customerData }: MoleculeSystemManagementCustomerDataProps): JSX.Element => {

  return (
    <div className='c-data'>
      <CustomerForm customerData={customerData} />
      <AddressForm formId='customer' customerData={customerData} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Child2

```
function AddressForm({formId customerData }): JSX.Element {

  const classes = useStyles();

  const { addressValue, addressValueNr, addressValueZip, addressValueCity, deviceAddress, deviceAddressNo, deviceZip, deviceCity } =  customerData; 


  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.borderedRow}>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3} className={classes.formColumn}>
        <div>        
        <InputField type='label' id='address' name={`${formId}-address`} value={formId === 'customer' ? addressValue : deviceAddress} label={'Street'} />
        </div>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3} className={classes.formColumn}>        
        <InputField type='label' id='city' name={`${formId}-city`} value={formId === 'customer' ? addressValueNr : deviceAddressNo} label={'Number'} />
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3} className={classes.formColumn}>        
        <InputField type='label' id='state' name={`${formId}-state`} value={formId === 'customer' ? addressValueZip : deviceZip} label={'ZIP'} />
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3} className={classes.formColumn}>        
        <InputField type='label' id='zip' name={`${formId}-zip`} value={formId === 'customer' ? addressValueCity : deviceCity} label={'ORT'} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
export default AddressForm;
```

Comment: can you try passing a `key` prop to `CustomerData` component and increment that key on `handleReset`

Comment: @Azzy I tried this now, but still doesn't update the values :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is occurring because the state is only being passed to the first child component.

If you look carefully, you'll see that during the passage from the child (1) to child(2) there's no state dealing with it. React is not going to update the value of your props if it's not a state.

Probably, you just need to create a state within the first child. Look the example:

## Child 1

```
export default ({nextStepAction, customerData }: MoleculeSystemManagementCustomerDataProps): JSX.Element => {
      const [addressIsDifferent, setAddressIsDifferent] = useState(true);
      const [customerDataState, setCustomerDataState] = useState(customerData)
    
      return (
        <div className='c-data'>
          <CustomerForm customerData={customerData} />
          <AddressForm formId='customer' customerData={customerDataState} />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Extra tips: I don't what are the use cases of your project, but I highly recommend you to take a look at React [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

It's a great idea to use it if you need to pass data through components that need the same data and do cohesive functions.

> In a typical React application, data is passed top-down (parent to child) via props, but such usage can be cumbersome for certain types of props (e.g. locale preference, UI theme) that are required by many components within an application. Context provides a way to share values like these between components without having to explicitly pass a prop through every level of the tree.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I tried your solution now but still those values don't update when I click reset. I know that it's not ok to props drill through several components but in my project now we can't use context or redux at this moment, unfortunately :(

Comment: Oh, sure, got it. Well, if you put the state like I said, I think you should now only coordinate your reset function in parent component to their children. For example: you can pass a callback function within your components and in the child ones you create another function that encapsulates the callback one while also resets the state of the child component. Probably there are more elegants ways of doing it, but that would work, I think.

Comment: Not sure I understand how to do it, can you show me on your code example?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are setting the state to the same data as it was initialised. you initialise it with `customerDataTest` and then set it to `customerDataTest`. same thing

Comment: Yes, because I need that when I click Reset button which triggers handleReset(), I need that the inputs to have the initial values.. But that's why React doesn't rerender children AddressForm and CustomerForm, right? But what do I need to do in order to achieve this functionality? I tried also with useEffect but still nothing happens.